# Select Row by Column1 Value to Select Column2 of same Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this:

```
id       count
23432    0
34242    1
12345    5
32235    20
45645    3
```

How can i select a ROW column(count) value **20** by the column(id) value **32235**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should be pretty straight-forward.

```
SELECT `count`
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 32235
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd260/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE count = 20 && value=32235;
```

Comment: OP just wants to select the count column of the row with id=32235.